# How to include log4j-{profile}.properties file inside application-{profile}.properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I have two profile specific application.properties files (application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties) and two log4j.properties files.
(Log4j-dev.properties and Log4j-prod.properties). I need to include log4j-dev.properties file inside application-dev.properties file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your spring boot app logging in application-*.properties using `logging.level.*`. Using `spring-boot-starter-logging` dependency.

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.com.howtodoinjava=DEBUG

#output to a temp_folder/file
logging.file=${java.io.tmpdir}/application.log

# Logging pattern for the console
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n

# Logging pattern for file
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%
```

Another solution is you can link to your external log4j configuration file using `logging.config=log4j.properties`

So for example in `application-dev.properties` create the line:

```
logging.config=classpath:Log4j-dev.properties
```

and in `application-prod.properties` create the line:

```
logging.config=classpath:Log4j-prod.properties
```

Comment: I tried this code, but I got an error.

Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:log4j-dev.properties'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:log4j-dev.properties